# Add two video to a canvas with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I modified this example code (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos):

```
ffmpeg
    -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -i 3.avi -i 4.avi
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
    "
    -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

to use only two videos (left and right):

```
./ffmpeg -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1856x578 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=928x578 [upperleft];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=928x578 [upperright];[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright]overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2] " -c:v libx264 combo.avi
```

But I always get the following error:

```
Filter overlay has an unconnected output
```

Any help would be great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your adapted code, it should be

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1856x578[base];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=928x578[upperleft];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=928x578[upperright];[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright]overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2] " -map "[tmp2]" -c:v libx264 combo.avi
```

You may want to confirm the `x` value in the overlay. I've left it unchanged but it probably should be `928`.

---

But the better way to do this is

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack" -c:v libx264 combo.avi
```